# Updating column based on previous record

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with Columns C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6 and Count. I have to order the records using order by C1, C2, C3, C4, C5. For 1st record Count will be 0 then if Values of C1, C2, C3, C4, C5 of the next row is same as previous row then I have to update the Count column by adding +1. So this is what I am expecting:
Table:

```
C1   C2    C3    C4    C5    C6     Count
-------------------------------------------
1    A     X     X1    AA    123     0
1    A     X     X1    AA    121     1
1    A     X     X1    AA    118     2
1    A     X     X1    AA    117     3
2    B     X     X2    AA    234     0
8    A     Y     X3    AA    298     0
8    A     Y     X3    AA    800     1
```

I am using Oracle DB. I wrote a PL SQL block with Cursor with Order by and then used the cursor in BULK COLLECT and iterated through each record compared with previous record. However, Count column is updated with unexpected record and taking much more time than expected, table have around 400k records. I unable to type my code here as actual code is in client machine. Any help is highly appreciated. One can use PL/SQL or Simple SQL. DB is Oracle.

Comment: Why do you need to write a PL/SQL block with cursor and BULK COLLECT and iterate through each row, etc.? Learning the proper way to do this in plain SQL is much easier and much more efficient - and it takes far less time to learn the proper SQL for this than to learn the PL/SQL for it. Then: Why do you need that ordering "count" in the table? It makes sense in a view, or in a query to produce a report; STORING it in a table can only cause problems in the future. What if a row is deleted in the future, or a C3 is corrected from Y to X? Now you have to recalculate the entire column! Bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (row_number() over (partition by c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 order by c6) - 1
       ) as "Count"
from t;
```

You can use `merge` to put this in an `update` statement.  Alternatively, if you really want an `update`:

```
update t
    set count = (select count(*)
                 from t t2
                 where t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.col2 = t.col2 and t2.col3 = t.col3 and
                       t2.col4 = t.col4 and t.col5 = t2.col5 and
                       t2.col6 < t.col6
                );
```

Comment: Thanks. Using your query I am able to crack the problem.

Comment: There's no rhyme or reason to the ordering by col6, not sure if you noticed. The OP shows "count" increasing for DESC ordering by col6 in the case of (A, X), but then for ASC ordering by col 6 in the case of (A, Y). Probably not worth looking further into it though, as the whole assignment really makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of hint provided by Gordon Linoff I am able to solve this issue. However., I created a new table instead of update to avoid performance issue. Below is the query:

```
CREATE TABLE TAB2 AS
SELECT T1.C1, T1.C2, T1.C3, T1.C4, T1.C5, T1.C6, T1.REC_COUNT 
(select t.*,
       (row_number() over (partition by c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 order by c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) - 1
       ) as rec_count
from tab1 T) T1;
```

Comment: Ordering by the same columns as those you partition by (or by a subset of them) results in random ordering - which seems to be what you want anyway; there is no obvious logic in the ordering you presented, within fixed c1 through c5. (The reason the ordering you have there is "random" is that it is WITHIN each partition, in which c1 through c5 are fixed for all rows in a partition.) You get exactly the same (random) result by omitting "order by c1, ..., c5" from the row_number() arguments completely. Just keep the partition by portion.